# Python request.get() after few seconds

Tags: python

I want to get html-text a few seconds after opening url.

Here's the code:

```
import requests
url = "http://XXXXX…"
html = request.get(url).text
```

Answer (score 5):

> I want to get html-text few seconds after opening url.

Well, the webpage HTML stays the same right after you "get" the url using Requests, so there's no need to wait a few seconds as the HTML will not change.

I assume the reason that you would like to wait is for the page to load all the relevant resources (e.g. CSS/JS) that modifies the HTML?
If it's so, I wouldn't recommend you using the Requests module as you will have to manipulate and load all of the relevant resources by yourself.

I suggest you to have a look at **[Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) for Python**.
Selenium fully simulates a browser, hence you can wait and it will load all the resources for your webpage.

Answer (score 3):

try using [`time.sleep(t)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep)

```
response = request.get(url)
time.sleep(5)  # suspend execution for 5 secs
html = response.text
```

Comment: Is this any different from the answer above?

Comment: @tbizzy0808 it is not just different, but also more appropriate way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You want to change the last line to:

```
html = requests.get(url).text
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the library `requests-html` handy for this purpose, though mostly I use Selenium (as already proposed in Danny answer).

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession, HTMLResponse

session = HTMLSession()
req = cast(HTMLResponse, session.get("http://XXXXX"))
req.html.render(sleep=5, keep_page=True)
```

Now, the `req.html` is a HTML object. In order to get the raw text or the html as a string you can use:

```
text = req.text
```

or:

```
text = req.html.html
```

Then you can parse your `text` string, e.g. with Beautiful Soup.

Answer (score -2):

basically you can give a sleep to the request as a parameter as bellow:

```
import requests
import time
url = "http://XXXXX…"
seconds = 5
html = requests.get(url,time.sleep(seconds)).text #for example 5 seconds
```

Comment: Nice, did not know this! How is this handled internally by requests? Is it just like passing anything else?

Comment: Well, this introduces delay BEFORE issuing the request, not after. It also relies on `time.sleep()` to return None, which is then used as request parameters, and cannot be used with actual parameters. Even though it is the most upvoted answer, this is the worst solution